# In Leaflet how can I calculate the distance to the furthest marker from a clicked marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My map allows a user to draw circles around a clicked marker. To keep it in bounds of the furthest marker I need to know where that furthest marker is. How do I find the furthest marker from a clicked marker? But to complicate things I need to read the furthest marker title information to make sure it's the correct type of marker. It would have a special 3 letter code in the title to test if it's the correct marker to use. I can only check if it's there not what it says.

Comment: If you need to keep things in bounds, use `L.FeatureGroup`s, `getBounds()` and `fitBounds()`. If you need to search for the farthest away point in a dataset, calculate the antipodal of the query point, keep the dataset in a r-tree, and perform a k-nearest-neighbour search.

Comment: @IvanSanchez OK well this gives me a lot to research and learn about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer was to calculate the furthest distance in all directions at the get go. I did this by first finding a bounding box by calculating the:

```
$minLat = $rowCorners[minLat]-0.25;
$maxLat = $rowCorners[maxLat]+0.25;
$minLng = $rowCorners[minLng]+0.25;
$maxLng = $rowCorners[maxLng]-0.25;
```

In this case I gave myself a little room to work in, exact distance were not that critical. By using that information it was easy to draw the circles needed by the users.